# How do I produce a list of URL links in a particular location?

Tags: python, url, pdf

I am trying to produce a list of files that branch from a certain URL.

Is this possible? Is it possible with Python??

The URL is: https://pace.oregonstate.edu/courses/sites/default/files/resources/pdf/

I want to produce a list of all the pdf files that are at this location.

One PDF is as follows:
https://pace.oregonstate.edu/courses/sites/default/files/resources/pdf/ch01_botany.pdf

How do I produce a list of other PDF files within the folder that contains "01_botany.pdf"?

Marshall

Comment: Could you please provide the code showing the effort you made so far?

Answer (score 0):

The top level link that you gave redirects onto itself so, without any other information to go on, you will not be able to discover the other files within that location.

If you happen to know the scheme that is being used to name the files then you could guess, e.g. ch01_botany.pdf is chapter one of a botany text, so you could guess that another file might be ch02_botany.pdf for the second chapter. However, accessing that URL redirects to a login page, so I guess that most of the content requires you to be a registered user. If you are a registered user, you could login and then perhaps guess, or even see, the list of files.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I really appreciate it!